# Missing DevForce VS Extension DLLs

Tags: visual-studio-2012, devforce

I just updated DevForce from 7.2.3 to 7.2.4 using the "Manage NuGet Packages" dialog in Visual Studio.  Because we've customized the code generation template, we copy IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Edm.Metadata.dll, IdeaBlade.VisualStudio.DTE.dll, and IdeaBlade.VisualStudio.OM.CodeGenerator.EF6.dll into a more accessible location.  Usually these DLLs are found in the following directory,

C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions

This time, however, a folder was not created in this directory with these DLLs.  I've restarted Visual Studio.  I've backed out of the upgrade and tried it again.  I tried running the setup.exe in packages\IdeaBlade.DevForce.Core.7.2.4\tools.  Are these files getting placed somewhere else now?  Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any differences between these releases in the installation of the EDM Designer Extension.  The tools folder in the installed package should contain a vsix named IdeaBlade.VisualStudio.OM.Designer.12.0.vsix, which you can double-click to install the extension.  This is normally installed during setup if needed, so I'm not sure what's happened here.